# How to make SwiftPM packages available for test target

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have tried to move our dependencies from CocoaPods to SwiftPM; But after doing so, our test target can no longer find any of the dependencies. I get: `Missing required modules: 'PackageName'`

I then tried to go to build phases on the test target and -> Link Binary with Libraries, and added them manually (which worked after a lot of fiddling). However, we have a lot of packages and adding them manually like this seems strange...

I would have expected that when you do `@testable import MainTarget` it would understand to include the packages?

Is there a better way of sharing the SwiftPM packages with other targets?